# Sharp error: [Error: Input file is missing]

Tags: node.js, request, sharp

I download the image through `request`, and then process the image through `sharp`.
But there is an error that input file is missing, actually the variable `body` has a value.

```
import { IADLandingPageABTest } from '@byted/ec-types';
import request from 'request';
import sharp from 'sharp';

const images: Array<keyof IADLandingPageABTest> = ['topPosterUrl', 'bottomPosterUrl'];

export default function handleImage (config: IADLandingPageABTest) {
    images.forEach(key => {
        const url = config[key];
        if (url && typeof url === 'string' ) {
           request(url, (err, response, body) => {
               //console.log('body', body);
               //body has a value
               if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
                sharp(body)
                .resize(100)
                .toBuffer()
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data.toString('base64'));
                })
                .catch( err => { console.log('error', err) });
               }
           })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I found some details which might help - https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/930#issuecomment-326833522

Comment: Did this work ?

Comment: @nopassport1 yep,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an issue on the `sharp` repo which outlines the solution:

> the `request` module expects `encoding` to be set to receive `body` as a `Buffer`.

```
- request(url, function(error, response, body) {
+ request({ url, encoding: null }, function(error, response, body) {
```

Source: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/930#issuecomment-326833522

Comment: Both sharp and request support streaming, so you could start processing the image as it's coming in, FYI.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to point out the mistake I did!

If you are using multer library which after having run keeps the buffer in **req.file**, then make sure the file/buffer that is being passed inside sharp is
correct.

The below was the code I used and I did faced the same error as mentioned in the question.(I have used multer for file upload)

```
 sharp(req.file)
 .resize({ width: 75,height: 75 })
 .toBuffer()
 .then(data => {
   console.log("data: ",data);
   res.send("File uploaded");
 }).catch(err =>{
  console.log("err: ",err);    
 });
```

req.file is an object!

```
req.file:  {
fieldname: 'file',
originalname: 'Sample.gif',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/gif',
buffer: <Buffer 47 49 46 38 39 61 57 04 56 02 f7 00 31 00 ff 00 09 73 22 0c 76 
14 33 23 ... 797643 more bytes>,
size: 797693
}
```

I have passed req.file which is inturn is an object which is not a file exactly.Rather **the buffer attribute inside req.file is my actual file buffer
that needs to be given inside sharp**

So by using the below, I didn't face any error and my code works!

```
 sharp(req.file.buffer)
 .resize({ width: 75,height: 75 })
 .toBuffer()
 .then(data => {
   console.log("data: ",data);
   res.send("File uploaded");
 }).catch(err =>{
  console.log("err: ",err);    
 });
```

Comment: Perfect Answer. 
Actually sharp want buffer.
I am using express-fileupload for upload a photo. I got the buffer as data.
data: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 08 06 00 00 00 f4 78 d4 fa 00 00 20 00 49 44 dd 07 78 5c e5 95 ...
So, I am using sharp(req.files.photo.data). Thank you.